# Pandas.concat() given DataFrame.append() are deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im a newbie to the programming, including Python.
I have been using Python to combine several excel files into one at work.
Now given DataFrame.append() is deprecated, i have been trying to modify my coding with Pandas.concat() but no luck.

```
....
files = os.listdir(folder)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(extension2):
        datafile = folder + '/' + file
        datafile1 = load_workbook(datafile)
        sh_name = datafile1.sheetnames
        for y in sh_name:
            data = pd.read_excel(datafile,sheet_name = y, header = 10)
            df = df.append(data)

df.to_excel(r'myfilepath\\append.xlsx', index= False, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
```

So i replaced the df.append in the second last line to

```
df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True)
```

Then got TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Can someone please help me here ?
Only have a few hours experience in programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
        for y in sh_name:
            data = pd.read_excel(datafile,sheet_name = y, header = 10)
            df = pd.concat([df, data], ignore_index=True)

# or
        dfs = []
        for y in sh_name:
            data = pd.read_excel(datafile,sheet_name = y, header = 10)
            dfs.append(data)
        df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```